# tee -a does not recreate file

Tags: rm, tee

I am running the following command on a Raspberry Pi 3 Debian latest release:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tee -a /media/pi/KINGSTON/klima.out | grep -F $ | tee -a /media/pi/KINGSTON/log
```

The command works fine and does what it should; however, when I delete (manually or by CRON) the `klima.out` file, it is not re-created. The command keeps running, the log file continues to be appended, but the `klima.out` file doesn't come back. (also no buffering). I want to delete it once a week for not letting it grow over all boundaries.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kusalananda, only in the `rc`/`es` or `fish` shells. Bourne-like shells and csh-like shells should be ok.

Comment: Kusalananda's answer is right; note that if your source was a growing log file instead of a device, you might want to "tail -f" so you don't re-cat what's already been processed.

Comment: Bear in mind that deleting a file (like with `rm`) is essentially an edit operation on a directory. It deletes the entry pointing to the file from the directory. The file itself will only be deleted when nothing is using it; but `tee` is using it.

Comment: This looks like a useless use of `cat`.  Instead, `tee < /dev/ttyUSB0 -a ... | ...` would work the same, but `tee` would read directly from the char dev instead of from a pipe from `cat`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to recover the file blocks, you need to blank the file, not unlink it:

This portable way should work with most shells :

```
: > /media/pi/KINGSTON/klima.out
```

Unlinking the file (i.e. `rm`) is removing the directory entry but doesn't affect the file contents (inode) as long as the file is kept open by readers or writers.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I just want to shorten the file. Sorry to bother, but I don't completely understand your suggested code. What does the : stand for?

Comment: `:` is the null command, i.e. it does nothing specific. The only feature used here is provided by the shell: the redirection is resetting the file to an empty content.

Comment: @jlliagre It does do something specific, it evaluates its arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda The null command doesn't evaluates its arguments. It really does nothing at all. The **shell** evaluates (i.e. expands) the null commands arguments when they are present, but this is not the case here, there are no arguments.

Comment: @jlliagre You're perfectly correct on both points.

Comment: `echo ""` would be an alternative but `:` is unbeatable short :-)

Comment: @Björn Indeed, although not strictly equivalent, `echo ""` would write one byte to the file. Note that `echo` alone does the same as `echo ""`.

Comment: @jlliagre You are right. I should have written `echo -n ""` to suppress the newline.

Comment: @Björn Well, `echo -n` behavior is implementation defined. Depending on the shell, this command might replace the file content with the string `-n` instead of fully truncating it. A portable way to write "nothing" is `printf ""`.

Comment: @Björn: Short but not unbeatably short.  `> /tmp/foo` truncates / creates `/tmp/foo`, with no command needed (tested with bash and dash, so I think this is posix-standard sh behaviour).

Comment: @PeterCordes `>/tmp/foo` is even shorter ;-) I didn't suggested a commandless redirection it because it fails with `csh` syntax based shells. Note that `: > /tmp/foo` fails too with the `fish` shell. With it, `true > /tmp/foo` can be used instead.

Answer (score 21):

I'm assuming that the pipeline of yours is running for a long time and that you are trying to remove the log file while it's running.

When you delete the file, the `tee` process still has it open for writing, which means that the disk space is not handed back to the system. That won't happen until all open file descriptors that references the file are closed.

It's perfectly OK to write to a file that's been deleted, as long as the file descriptor was allocated before the deletion.

You will have to restart the pipeline for the file to be recreated, and to allow the space taken by the old (now nameless) log file to be reclaimed.

To avoid having to restart the pipeline, you may choose to *truncate* the file, i.e. trim its size down to zero without removing it. This would allow `tee` to continue appending to the file without having to re-open it.

Truncating a file may be done [like jlliagre showed in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367921/116858), or by using `truncate` (a non-standard utility which is part of GNU coreutils):

```
truncate -s 0 /media/pi/KINGSTON/klima.out
```

See [the manual for `truncate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/truncate-invocation.html) for further info about that utility.

Comment: *as long as the file descriptor was allocated before the deletion*.  Actually, you can get new file descriptors for already-deleted-but-still-open files through `/proc/pid/fd`.  It's also perfectly fine to write through those, too.  So really, as long as you have an open file descriptor, the number of directory entries for that inode is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: After truncating, the next write to the still-open fd will result in a sparse file, so yes this does recover the space but you have that many bytes of zeros before the new text, because it doesn't reset the file position of already-open fds.  (And some filesystems don't support sparse files, e.g. FAT or HFS+, so the next write will actually write zeros).  Anyway, I don't think there's any way around that (other than a ptrace / debugger hack that resets the file position of `tee`'s fd as well as truncating).

Comment: Anyway,  you could also just punch a hole out to the current len with [`fallocate -p`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html), but then you need the right length and all it gains you is saving one inode update (never needs to set the length to zero).

Comment: @PeterCordes I tested this and it does not seem to create a sparse file. A 100M file opened in append mode, then truncated as above. The next write to it will occur at the start of the now empty file, not after some sparse gap, as far as I can see.

Comment: In your testing, you probably closed and re-opened the file.  I'm talking about the case where you *don't restart the pipeline*, like you mentioned.  Test this by doing `cat > /tmp/foo` and type a few lines.  Leave it running while you go to another tab and truncate the file, then type some more lines into the `cat`.  A hexdump (`hd /tmp/foo`) shows a bunch of zeros, out to the previous file-position of `cat`'s fd.  You can also look at `/proc/$(pidof cat)/fdinfo/1` to see its file position.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, yes, if you use `>`, but _not_ if you use `>>` or, as the OP was doing, `tee -a`. Writing in append mode always adds to the logical end of the file whereas not using append mode will write at the physical location after the last write.

Comment: You're right!  I wasn't expecting O_APPEND to make an already-open file-descriptor react to changes in the file's length.  That's cool.  Before now, I thought it was pretty much equivalent to doing an `lseek(SEEK_END)` after opening, with no persistent effects.

Comment: I was curious about the details of how this works, and found [this explanation of exactly what `O_APPEND` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223661/o-append-flag-and-lseek):  Every `write(2)` implicitly does an `lseek` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 4):

You don't understand how the system is handling files.

You delete the file entry, but the file still exists as long as the program keeps an handle on it. So tee is never notified the entry was deleted and it still writes to the file !

A unique file can have many entries thanks to the hard links (created by the ln command).

You could write your own version of tee which close and open the file on every line it writes to the file, but it would be very under-performing as it would generate so many system calls.

Here is a shell-function which will split its input to several files :

```
splitSizeInKio=100

splitInput(){
    local PS4='+splitInput+ '
    set -x
    local i=0
    local fname="$1"
    local ii

    while true
    do if [ $i -lt 10 ]
       then ii=0$i
       else ii=$i
       fi
       local outfile="$fname".$ii
       dd of="$outfile" bs=1024 count=$splitSizeInKio
       i=$((i+1))
    done
}
```

(You could use "head" instead of "dd" if you spilt on a number of lines instead of a size.)

With bash, you can use "process substitution" like this :

```
prog1 | tee >( splitInput somefilename ) | prog2
```

Comment: Your splitInput might work ok using `dd`, since it "knows" exactly how many bytes to read from it's stdin, but using `head` is highly likely to result in corrupted data, due to buffering.

Comment: Yeah, `head` will read more data from stdin than it writes, since it doesn't read 1 char at a time.  And it doesn't try to "put back" any over-read beyond the number of lines it was looking for (if that's even possible on pipes).